# Vectors and physics in games

Tags: math, vector

Can forces be stored as dot products? such as the gravity on a planet.

And for a game, for example a 2d spaceship game. would one add a right thrust vector and a left vector to power the ship and move it around. then this would mean the angle of the ship shown on screen is computed from those vectors and the player would have no control over the actual angle of the ship.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for your first question, yes. Why wouldn't you be able to? Though I would store gravity as just a value, and then calculate the weight of the object.

If I understand you, you are asking whether you should have the right key of a spaceship as a vector force to move left or to have the right key rotate the ship? The first idea seems more logical; if your spaceship is stuck in a place such as this:

```
  _
 |*|
 | |
_| |___
|_______
```

(Excuse my poor ASCII; it's meant to be a ship stuck in a vertical dead end) your first solution would cause the ship to ricochet in the tunnel. Your second solution (applying a rotation directly) would simply have a ship rotating. Which would seem very unnatural if the tunnel was narrow.

Look up rotation matrices.

Answer (score 1):

> Can forces be stored as dot products?
> such as the gravity on a planet.

This makes ***no sense whatsoever***.  A force is a vector; dot product is the scalar product of two vectors.

> And for a game, for example a 2d
> spaceship game. would one add a right
> thrust vector and a left vector to
> power the ship and move it around.
> then this would mean the angle of the
> ship shown on screen is computed from
> those vectors and
>
> the player would
> have no control over the actual angle
> of the ship.

Huh?

Would you allow the player to vary the magnitudes of either vector?  If yes, then they have some control.

What does "left" and "right" vector mean to you?  What do they mean if the ship rotates 90 degrees?  Do they become "up" and "down"?  How does that change things?

Would you agree that if you have "left" and "right" vectors of equal magnitude that sum of forces in the x-direction is zero and the ship will not accelerate at all?  (You make no mention of vectors in the y-direction, so I'll assume that the sum of forces in the y-direction is zero, too.)

> Is this correct?

No.

Your understanding of Newtonian mechanics is equal to your current acceptance rate.

Comment: left and right relate to thrusters at the rear of the spaceship. How can gravity itself be represented by a vector as it affect objects from all directions?

Comment: "all directions"?  No, it's a vector that runs from the centroid of the rocket to the centroid of the planet.  When I step on my scale in the morning, gravity pulls me down in proportion to my mass, the mass of the earth, and the inverse square of the distance from my centroid to the center of the earth.  My scale pushes up with a force that's equal in magnitude and opposite to its direction, so I don't fly off into space or fall through the floor.  Gravity has a very definite direction.

Comment: In a 2D system, with the surface of the "planet" along the x-axis at y = 0, gravity acts in the negative y-direction.  It pulls a body like your rocket down towards the surface  with a force that's proportional to its mass.  As for your thrusters, left and right are good, but don't you need a thruster that pushes along the axis of the rocket as well?  That's what I see when I watch the Space Shuttle take off.  So the thruster pushes the nose of the rocket forward, and the left-right thrusters can rotate the nose about the centroid, because they're further back towards the base of the rocket.